# launchd disk writes

Tags: macos, launchd

Using activity monitor, I've noticed that launchd with pid 1 is using a lot of disk writes: after about 8 hours of light use, it's done ~2GB bytes written. Is it normal behavior? If not, how shall I troubleshoot this issue? I'm on the latest version if Yosemite, MacBook Pro 13" retina. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't fix things which ain't broken. As long as you don't experience performance or stability issues, you usually don't need to worry about particular processes.

My Mac hasn't been rebooted since two weeks, `launchd` has written 46 GB so far.

Comment: Thanks! On a side note, will this affect ssd write lifespan much?

Comment: @egwenesedai define your SSD lifespan and define much :)

Comment: @bmike I was thinking about ~5 years but realized you might be sarcastic :-) no need to worry on a modern ssd right?

Comment: @egwenesedai I was totally serious. I love data / SSD wear patterns, ways to manage replacement risk, etc... Start a new thread if you have a question on this :-) http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13884/, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71750/ and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18328/ could use some new answers if you have a new question